# Simplifying x3 queries

Tags: google-bigquery

Looking for some help to simplify a x3 query script, hopefully into 1(sub query perhaps). See script below. The main issue is getting to a return result of 1 row per customer. Any Customer has the potential to transact accross multiple channels which ultimately causes duplicates. I've work around this by creating x3 queries. I'd love to get this neater. BigQuery

I'd also like to understand if there's a way I can query against week number, opposed to changing dates.
Hoping you can help.

```
####THIS SPEC IS BASED ON 2020 WEEK24####
####UPDATE MONDAY TO SUNDAY DATE PARAMETERS####
####UPDATE WK NUMBER TABLE NAME####

##CREATES INITIAL TRANSACTION TABLE##
drop table ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_1;
Create table ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_1 as
select 
t1.CustomerUID,
t1.transactionUID,
t1.siteUID as BRANCH_ID,
t1.salesChannel as CHANNEL,
t1.transactionDate,
##count(t1.CustomerUID) as CUST_ID_COUNT,
##count(t1.transactionUID) as TOT_ITEMS,
Max(t1.transactionDate) as LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE,
Sum(t1.quantity*t1.grossSalePrice) AS TOTAL_SALE
from 
sales.customerTransactions t1
Join
ts_marketing.ts_cleaned_table t2
On
t1.CustomerUID = t2.ucu_uid
where
t1.quantity*t1.grossSalePrice > 0.00
and
t1.transactionDate >= '2020-06-15 00:00:00 UTC'
and 
t1.transactionDate < '2020-06-22 00:00:00 UTC'
and
t1.salesChannel In ('Branches', 'Contact Centre', 'Web', 'Click & Collect')
and
t1.isCancelled = 0
and
t1.transactionType ='Sale'
and
t2.ucu_email like "%@%"
and
t2.Email_Opt_In is true
group by 1,2,3,4,5;

##CREATES SINGLE CUSTOMER AT LATEST TRANSACTION LEVEL##
##Drop Table ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_2;
Create Table ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_2 as
Select
CustomerUID,
Max(LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE) as LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE
from
ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_1
group by 1;

##CREATES SINGLE CUSTOMER AT LATEST TRANSACTION LEVEL WITH ADDITIONAL FIELD REQUIREMENTS##
##Drop Table ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_3;
Create Table ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_3 as
Select
t1.CustomerUID,
t2.BRANCH_ID,
t2.CHANNEL,
t2.TOTAL_SALE
#t1.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE,
from ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_2 t1
Left Join
ts_analytics.CRM_WR_CX_SURVEY_TEST_1 t2
on t1.CustomerUID = t2.CustomerUID
and t1.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE = t2.LAST_TRANSACTION_DATE
group by 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: mySQL or BigQuery?

Comment: Sorry, BigQuery

Comment: Mysql tag removed. Thanks for heads up Mikhail

Comment: Can you add sample data? Seeing how is the information in the table, and what is the expected result will help.